# PolicyKit daemon disconnected from the bus. Error when starting services without sudo on the super user account

Tags: networking, ssh, xrdp, policykit

Hopefully this will be a quick fix, but I have been having a consistent error whenever I try and start a service on my machine.

Whether it be ssh, rdp or apache2, whenever I try and launch the service using the basic command `service ssh start` for example I am greeted by an error message in my terminal saying the following:

```
PolicyKit daemon disconnected from the bus.
We are no longer a registered authentication agent.
Failed to start ssh.service: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
See system logs and 'systemctl status ssh.service' for details.
```

Running the command with a `sudo` in front of it seems to fix this issue for `ssh`, and it seems to "work" at first for the other services on my machine. However upon trying to connect to my webserver or my remote desktop service I am simply unable to connect to them.

Also upon rebooting I am also greeted by a system program problem prompt, and I am not told any information about the error.

I am fairly new to Ubuntu so I am unsure as to what may be causing this issue. if anyone can give me advice I would greatly appreciate it.

**These are the error logs given to me by the syslog file: These errors crop up every time i try to launch a service without the sudo command.**

```
Jun 3 17:12:26 xxxspermmonkey420xxx kernel: [ 1402.059083] polkitd[5560]: segfault at 8 ip 00007f6c77c88e36 sp 00007ffc95a7a5a0 error 4 in libpolkit-backend-1.so.0.0.0[7f6c77c79000+18000]
Jun 3 17:12:26 xxxspermmonkey420xxx systemd[1]: polkitd.service: Main process exited, code=dumped, status=11/SEGV
Jun 3 17:12:26 xxxspermmonkey420xxx gnome-session[4459]: PolicyKit daemon disconnected from the bus.
Jun 3 17:12:26 xxxspermmonkey420xxx gnome-session[4459]: We are no longer a registered authentication agent.
Jun 3 17:12:26 xxxspermmonkey420xxx systemd[1]: polkitd.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jun 3 17:12:26 xxxspermmonkey420xxx systemd[1]: polkitd.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.
Jun 3 17:12:26 xxxspermmonkey420xxx NetworkManager[1083]: <warn> [1528060346.4188] error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.reload: Authorization check failed: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
Jun 3 17:12:26 xxxspermmonkey420xxx NetworkManager[1083]: <warn> [1528060346.4189] error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.hos tname: Authorization check failed: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
Jun 3 17:12:26 xxxspermmonkey420xxx NetworkManager[1083]: <warn> [1528060346.4190] error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.own : Authorization check failed: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
Jun 3 17:12:26 xxxspermmonkey420xxx NetworkManager[1083]: <warn> [1528060346.4191] error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.sys tem: Authorization check failed: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
Jun 3 17:12:26 xxxspermmonkey420xxx NetworkManager[1083]: <warn> [1528060346.4191] error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.wifi.share.open: Authorization check failed: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
Jun 3 17:12:26 xxxspermmonkey420xxx NetworkManager[1083]: <warn> [1528060346.4192] error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.wifi.share.protecte d: Authorization check failed: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
Jun 3 17:12:26 xxxspermmonkey420xxx NetworkManager[1083]: <warn> [1528060346.4193] error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.network-control: Authorization check failed: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
Jun 3 17:12:26 xxxspermmonkey420xxx NetworkManager[1083]: <warn> [1528060346.4194] error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-wimax: Authorization check failed: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
Jun 3 17:12:26 xxxspermmonkey420xxx NetworkManager[1083]: <warn> [1528060346.4194] error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-wwan: Authorization check failed: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
Jun 3 17:12:26 xxxspermmonkey420xxx NetworkManager[1083]: <warn> [1528060346.4196] error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-wifi: Authorization check failed: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
Jun 3 17:12:26 xxxspermmonkey420xxx NetworkManager[1083]: <warn> [1528060346.4196] error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.sleep-wake: Authorization check failed: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
Jun 3 17:12:26 xxxspermmonkey420xxx dbus[1056]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1' unit='polkitd.service'
Jun 3 17:12:26 xxxspermmonkey420xxx NetworkManager[1083]: <warn> [1528060346.4197] error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-network: Authorization check failed: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
Jun 3 17:12:26 xxxspermmonkey420xxx systemd[1]: Starting Authenticate and Authorize Users to Run Privileged Tasks...
Jun 3 17:12:26 xxxspermmonkey420xxx polkitd[5609]: started daemon version 0.105 using authority implementation `local' version `0.105'
Jun 3 17:12:26 xxxspermmonkey420xxx dbus[1056]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1'
Jun 3 17:12:26 xxxspermmonkey420xxx systemd[1]: Started Authenticate and Authorize Users to Run Privileged Tasks.
Jun 3 17:12:26 xxxspermmonkey420xxx gnome-session[4459]: PolicyKit daemon reconnected to bus.
Jun 3 17:12:26 xxxspermmonkey420xxx gnome-session[4459]: Attempting to re-register as an authentication agent.
Jun 3 17:12:26 xxxspermmonkey420xxx gnome-session[4459]: We are now a registered authentication agent.
```